# margin spaces in latex

Tags: margins

I try to fit the margin in my thesis from each side 1 in and whatever I did, I does not work.
whatever I use:

```
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

or

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

it does not work.  Besides I use the \usepackage{ConcordiaU} which is for paper definitions page for the first page of thesis and style customized for Concordia university, which includes these also:

```
\makeatletter
\oddsidemargin 0.5in 
\evensidemargin 0.5in
\marginparwidth 40pt 
\marginparsep 10pt
\topmargin 0in 
\headsep 0in %-0.1 topmargin
\textheight 8.75in 
\textwidth 6in %9in textheight
```

What shall I do for fit the margin to 1 inch?
Thanks

Comment: `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` should work, except if some other package redefines margins after you load `geometry `.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  If you're writing your thesis for the institution that provides the thesis class file, it's not a good idea to change the specified formatting; that could be cause for rejection, or a requirement for you to reformat the document.

Comment: Maybe, trying just to load `geometry` and add `\AtBeginDocument{\geometry{margin=1in}}`?